One of my site data dumps appears to be giving a false positive for having a virus - what should I do?
I'm a moderator at Super User, and downloaded the dumps for that site. The 'main' dump's fine. The dump for meta failed because Windows detected it as having a virus. Since I got it from SE (and other checks) I am reasonably certain it's the file and not me.

I've decompressed the file and confirmed the individual XML files are clean. Strangely the files came out clean on virus total. I believe it's very likely a false positive.
This might make it difficult for folks to download the file (on Windows)—and might indicate some quirks in the data dump process.
What'd be the appropriate action if I came across this in terms of reporting?

I'm gradually downloading the files manually, while waiting on a request to get a 'bulk' download.
For the sake of easier investigation (and the need to download and verify these dumps on another machine) - so far I've had detections on meta.superuser.com and meta.askubuntu.com, and will update as I go along

I believe its a different file from what's in IA so it won't help

Ah, came out clean on my torrented copy

Also tried decompressing and recompressing my copy... no luck there either

This isn't particularly new. The Monero dump has caused problems for the company before, plus a couple other crypto sites. While I was on the DBRE team, I worked with Archive.org to have the dumps added to an allow list to prevent their antivirus scans from flagging the dump & taking it offline.  I have no good advice other than to tell your antivirus to ignore it

That was the content wasn't it? In this case the content inside is clean. I'm not actually sure what's triggering it

@JourneymanGeek It was the 7z files that we upload that were flagged. I don't know what type of security software or scans were flagging it--maybe they were cracking the 7z open to scan contents or maybe it was something about the compressed file itself---but if you're seeing an issue with a crypto site, then it would almost certainly be the same issue

I don’t think there’s any way to avoid this. The sites can legitimately contain samples that scanners could understandably detect as potential threats. Perhaps this could be ameliorated by warning users of the possibility and providing a hash in case they want to verify the download.

Well, I did the former, asked for the latter :D
